# RabbitMQ MQTT SSL connection fails

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, mqtt, tls1.2

I am trying to set up a RabbitMQ server with mqtt and amqp connections. 
I have opened mqtt tcp connection on port 1883 and mqtt ssl connection on port 8883. TLS and SSL listners are successfully opened as the log. I am using mqttBox as the client and I can successfully connect to port 1883 using tcp. But I am unable to connect to port 8883 using TLS/SSL.

Here is my config file.

```
[
 {rabbit,
  [
   {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672}, {"::1", 5672}]},
   {default_vhost, <<"/">>},
   {default_user, <<"user">>},
   {default_pass, <<"bitnami">>},    
   {default_permissions, [<<".*">>, <<".*">>, <<".*">>]},

   {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,  "/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/tls/result/ca_certificate.pem"},
                {certfile,   "/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/tls/result/server_certificate.pem"},
                {keyfile,    "/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/tls/result/server_key.pem"},
  %%                  {password,""},
                {verify,     verify_peer},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]}
  %%     {ssl_listeners, [5671]}

  ]
  },
  {kernel, []},
  {rabbitmq_management,
  [
   {listener, [{port, 15672}, {ip, "0.0.0.0"}]}
  ]
 },
 {rabbitmq_shovel,
  [
   {shovels, []}
  ]
 },
 {rabbitmq_stomp, []},
 {rabbitmq_mqtt, [{ssl_cert_login, true}, {allow_anonymous, false} , 
  {ssl_listeners,    [8883]}, {tcp_listeners,    [1883]}]},
  {rabbitmq_amqp1_0, []},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, []},
  {rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.6}]
 }
].
```

And my log file.

```
started MQTT TCP Listener on [::]:1883
started MQTT SSL Listener on [::]:8883
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672
started SSL Listener on [::]:5671


<0.13639.4> MQTT vhost picked using plugin configuration or default
```

TCP connection successful

```
 <0.13639.4> accepting MQTT connection <0.13639.4> (123.231.123.82:54601 -> 10.128.0.5:1883)
```

TLS connection failed

```
 <0.13639.4> MQTT detected network error for "123.231.123.82:54601 -> 10.128.0.5:1883": peer closed TCP connection
```

It seems both tcp and tls requests are headed to 10.128.0.5:1883.

How can I fix this?

edit: client configurations:
[image]

Comment: Edit the question to include the details of your client so we can see how you are trying to connect

Comment: I've not used MQTTBox, but if the incoming connection is being seen on port 1883 then it's most likely either a bug or miss configured client